# Flutter custom painter drawRect doesnt work correctly

Tags: flutter, flutter-custompainter

I want to draw on my pictures. I just implemented the ability to draw rectangles. Of course I want to see when I drag my finger across the screen how the size of the rectangle changes. I worked with a GestureDetector widget to detect the movement. At first touch I create the rectangle and as long as the finger stays on the screen the one rectangle is updated.
Problem is, I only see the finished rectangle when I remove my finger from the screen.

If I use the onPanUpdate method instead of always drawing new rectangles, I can see the drawn rectangles.

I have also tried always deleting the old rectangle or setting the color to transparent and creating a new one which leads to the same behavior as above.

Hier ist the GestureDetector widget:

```
GestureDetector canvasEdit(
  ui.Image backgroundImage, BuildContext innerContext) {
return GestureDetector(
  onPanDown: (details) {
    RenderBox renderBox = innerContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    Offset localPosition = renderBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);

    if (currentMode == PainterMode.paintrect) {
      start = localPosition;

      setState(() {
        items.add(DrawingRectangle(
            start: start!,
            end: start!,
            color: currentColor,
            strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
            filled: fillWithColor));
      });
    }
  },
  onPanUpdate: (details) {
    RenderBox renderBox = innerContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    Offset localPosition = renderBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);

    if (currentMode == PainterMode.freestyle) {
      setState(() {
        items.add(DrawingPoint(
            point: localPosition,
            color: currentColor,
            strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
            filled: false));
      });
    } else if (currentMode == PainterMode.paintrect) {
      if (items.last is DrawingRectangle) {
        setState(() {
          // (items.last as DrawingRectangle).color = Colors.transparent;
          // items.last = null;
          // items.add(DrawingRectangle(
          //     start: start!,
          //     end: transformedPosition,
          //     color: currentColor,
          //     strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
          //     filled: fillWithColor));
          (items.last as DrawingRectangle).end = localPosition;
          print(
              'update rect: ${(items.last as DrawingRectangle).start} : ${(items.last as DrawingRectangle).end}');
        });
      }
    } else if (currentMode == PainterMode.cleaning) {
      // Entferne Punkte, die sich in der Nähe des Radierers befinden
      for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i] != null && items[i] is DrawingPoint) {
          if ((items[i]?.point - localPosition).distance < strokeWidth) {
            setState(() {
              items[i] = null;
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  onPanEnd: (details) {
    if (currentMode == PainterMode.freestyle) {
      setState(() {
        items.add(null);
      });
    }
    if (currentMode == PainterMode.paintrect) {
      setState(() {
        start = null;
        items.add(null);
      });
    }
    bool clearFollowing = itemsHistory.length - 1 != currentHistoryIndex;
    updateHistory(clearFollowing);
  },
  child: CustomPaint(
    painter: MyPainter(backgroundImage, items),
    child: Container(),
  ),
);
```

}

And here ist MyPainter Class

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:levelbuild_document_demo/custom_painter/drawing_objects.dart';

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<dynamic> items;
  final ui.Image backgroundImage;

  MyPainter(this.backgroundImage, this.items);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    paintImage(
      canvas: canvas,
      rect: Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
      image: backgroundImage,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    );

    Paint paint = Paint();

    for (int i = 0; i < items.length - 1; i++) {
      if (items[i] != null) {
        paint.color = items[i]!.color;
        paint.strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;
        paint.strokeWidth = items[i]!.strokeWidth;
        paint.style =
            items[i]!.filled ? PaintingStyle.fill : PaintingStyle.stroke;
        if (items[i] is DrawingPoint && items[i + 1] is DrawingPoint) {
          canvas.drawLine(items[i]!.point, items[i + 1]!.point, paint);
        }
        if (items[i] is DrawingRectangle) {
          Offset topLeft = (items[i] as DrawingRectangle).start;
          Offset bottomRight = (items[i] as DrawingRectangle).end;

          canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromPoints(topLeft, bottomRight), paint);
          print('draw rect $i: $topLeft : $bottomRight');
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: no that doesnt works, the behavior remains the same, that rectangles are only visible when onPanEnd is reached.

Comment: no, they are visible when you call `onPanUpdate` - just run the code I posted *without* any changes

Comment: thx, i will try to adjust my code.